# In javscript, how to show Session timeout based on cookie expiry

Tags: javascript, session, session-cookies

We are maintaining session token in cookies which gets expired every 60 mins. Basically cookie has a expiry of 60 mins. But We have a requirement to show Session timeout popup 5 min before cookie expiry (on 55th min of after cookie got created). But the issue is, we cannot read the cookie expiry in JavaScript. I would like to know if there is any other way to do this in javascript?

This question is not about how to check intervals, but how do we get the cookie expiry?

Comment: `document.cookie` does not have cookie expiration details, you can have another cookie variable holding value as expiry time.

Comment: cookie is created via server, I didn't get this approach of another cookie variable. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I am suggesting creating another cookie having the value as the expiry date. You can access this value from JS and consume it to solve the purpose.

Comment: But how would i read the value of the original cookie, and assign it to new cookie? Basically, how to read the expiry of original cookie?

Comment: @Rayon Can you pls reply to above question?

Comment: When you are assigning expiry to cookie "A", you should set the value of cookie "B" as the expiry date.

For eg. If cookie "session" = "SOME VALUE" and is set to expire at "'Sun, 20 Mar 2022 08:00:00 GMT'", set cookie "session_expire" with value "'Sun, 20 Mar 2022 08:00:00 GMT'"

Comment: @Rayon - I am not assigning the expiry to cookie. It's set by server. Basically, when i login,server creates that cookie in my browser. Since i cannot read the expiry of the cookie which is created by server, how can i set the same expiry to another cookie variable.

Comment: I believe this server belongs to you are you have a control over it :)